# Encryption function in C++

Tags: c++, strlen

So I tried making a function in C++ that converts each character entered by a user into a '*'. But when I run the .exe file (CMD) it asks for the password alright, however when I enter a word it gives me an error: "Debug assertion failed." Any idea why this happens?

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "string"
#include "ctype.h"

using namespace std;

void encrypt(char string[], int len)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < len; count++)
        if (isalpha (string [count] ) )
            string[count] = '*';
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char Text[40];
    int Size = strlen(Text);
    cout << "Enter your desired password: ";
    cin >> Text;
    encrypt(Text, Size);
    cout << Text << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using the debugger? At what the error is thrown?

Comment: Your question is Windows specific. Your code won't run on Posix systems! Linux provides http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt and much more

Comment: This doesn't look like encryption to me. Your function seems to simply turn every alpha numeric character in your string into an asterisk.

Comment: You should initialize with all zeros your `Text` with `memset(Text, 9, sizeof(Text));` and you should call `strlen` after the user input

Comment: I meant `memset(Text, 0, sizeof(Text));` sorry for the typo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move "int Size = strlen(Text) after the line "cin >> Text;"

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop doesnt take into account the length of the input text. Instead it supplys Size by calling strlen on the un-initialzised char array which will usually be full of random values. **Your compiler should warn you about this**. Don't ignore warnings all the time.

```
char Text[40];
int Size = strlen(Text);
```

As strlen follows the sequence of characters until it finds NUL ( 0x0 ) it is probably falling off of the end of the 40 character space into some other part of your stack so giving you a runtime error ( Segmentation Violation )

Answer (score 0):

strlen(Text) gives back the lenght of the string by searching for the '\0'. You should do this after the user has entered the text.

```
char Text[40];
cout << "Enter your desired password: ";
cin >> Text;
int Size = strlen(Text);
encrypt(Text, Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You took the size of the text from before the text was entered.

```
...
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char Text[40];
    // int Size = strlen(Text); // to early
    cout << "Enter your desired password: ";
    cin >> Text;
    int Size = strlen(Text); // now Text is filled and the Size will not change.
    encrypt(Text, Size);
    cout << Text << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the line

```
int ln 〓 strlen(Text);
```

too early, as the text had not been entered by the user. You need to move it after the line:

```
cin >> Text;
```

For it to work.